# Image + String stored in an Array to be displayed in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

So I'm pretty new in C# and I am trying to develop this thing that does cataloging.

At first I tried 2 forms. One to display all the items and another for input but that was kind of challenging so I switched to 1 form. My goal is to store 3 inputs from the user.

1. Image(Picture Box)
2. Title(Text Box)
3. Category(Combo Box)

and display them in the ListView like you would see it normally in windows(thumbnail view)

and also have this kind of filter according to their categories(radio buttons)

This is what I have so far

[Product Catalog App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96uWU.png)

[EDIT]

All this does is reset the text box and the picture box.

- How would I display the inputs in the ListView and retain it for when
  I open the app again?
- How would I display only a certain category?

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //private Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
    private class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public Item(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Category.Items.Add(new Item("Books"));
        Category.Items.Add(new Item("Games"));
        Category.Items.Add(new Item("Music"));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Form2 frm = new Form2();
        // frm.Show();

        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(pictureBox1.ImageLocation);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Category.Text);
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "";
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Image picture = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question here ...

Comment: I surmise you mean winform programming, but there is a listview in asp.net and wpf...so which is it? Reply by editing your tags please.

Comment: @OmegaMan, it has to be `Winform` by seeing this in posted code `public partial class Form1 : Form`

Comment: @OmegaMan im sorry for my lack in clarity. this is winform